# Compara tamanho dos arquivos selecionados no input com o disk_free_space do PHP

Tags: php, jquery, upload, script

Preciso de um script em javascript quer compare os tamanho arquivos selecionados no `input` com o `disk_free_space` (no meu caso `disk_free_space('D:')`") do `PHP`, mas tem de ser antes de enviar para a pagina que faz o upload, e ao detectar que é maior do que o disponível, que bloqueie o botão e mostre uma mensagem, pois estou usando o `AJAX` para enviar, estou usando envio de múltiplos arquivos e tenho disponível o `JQuery`.

```html
<form id="formFiles" name="formFiles" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" required name="arquivo[]" multiple="multiple">
  <button id="" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possívél fazer. Basta utilizar `element.files` ou `$("input").prop("files")`, com isso você terá acesso ao *metadata* do arquivo (tamanho, *mimetype* etc).

**Exemplo comentado:**

```js
/* Como o aqui não irá funcionar o código PHP, deixarei comentado */
//const MAX_FILESIZE = parseInt("<?php echo disk_free_space('D:'); ?>")

/* Exemplo do valor retornado no código anterior */
const MAX_FILESIZE = 2000000

$("input:file").change(function() {
  
  /* Reinicia o tamanho acumulado */
  let size = 0
  
  /* Captura o metada dos arquivos escolhidos e percorrer todos eles */
  Array.from($(this).prop("files")).map( file => {
    
    /* Soma o tamanho do arquivo em bytes com o tamanho acumulado */
    size += file.size
  })
  
  /**
   * Habilita o botão caso `size` seja menor que `MAX_FILESIZE`,
   * caso contrário desabilita
   */
  $("button:submit").prop("disabled", (size > MAX_FILESIZE))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formFiles" name="formFiles" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" required name="arquivo[]" multiple="multiple">
  <button id="" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```